# How to load a different header based on post format?

Tags: posts, theme-development, headers, post-formats

I have a difficult question. What's the best way to load a different header based on a post format? I guess I could load another loop around the header but I noticed the site does slow down. This is the code on my index.php:

```
<?php get_header();?>

<section id="block">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</section>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you need different header ( get_header() ) in single post format ?

Comment: "what is best?" type of questions are almost never good questions, best for what and when? please edit the question and try to be as specific as possible. For example you talk about a second loop, but don't show it... a second loop if done right in theory should not have any impact on noticeable performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say if your have `header-video.php` used for video post format.

Replace `get_header();` with `get_header(get_post_format());` in your regular `singular.php` or `index.php`. If WP can find `header-video.php` it will load it otherwise it will automatically will fallback to `header.php`.